# php function calls with and without brackets

Tags: php, function, laravel, class

When using relationships in laravel it is possible to call a relationship function with or without brackets:

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post');
}

$user->posts();
$user->posts;
```

The first call will return an instance of the query builder and the second call will return an array of all the posts.

How is this feature made?

Comment: You could simply have taken a look yourself. Laravel is open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is done by implementing the [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) magic method:

```
class User {
  private $posts = [1, 2, 3];

  public function __get($key) {
    if ($key === 'posts')
      return $this->$key;
  }

  public function posts() {
    return count($this->posts);
  }
}

$u = new User;
var_dump($u->posts());
var_dump($u->posts);
```

*Output*

```
int(3)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```